# Converting String array to Enum in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, types, enums

I am playing around with Typescript a little.

Suppose I have an `object` such as this

```
let colors = {
    RED: "r",
    GREEN: "g",
    BLUE: "b"
}
```

Now I want to convert this into an `enum` type

```
enum Colors = {
    RED = "r",
    GREEN = "g",
    BLUE = "b"
}
```

**Update:**

I want the generated `typings` for the *colors* object such that
if I add another `key` to the colors object, It should be included in the `typings`.

If I do

```
colors['YELLOW'] = "y"
```

then the generated `typings` should be

```
declare enum colors {
    RED = "r",
    GREEN = "g",
    BLUE = "b",
    YELLOW = "y"
}
```

instead, the generate typings are

```
declare const colors {
     [x: string]: string        
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What useage do you have in mind? Don't think you can create an actual enum type based on an object literal, but you can create an object that closely mimicks the behavior of one.

Comment: You can do the opposite - convert `enum` to object

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I have updated the Question with what I actually want to achieve

Comment: I expected an Array, not an Object. Your question title is completely unrelated to the body. This would be an Array: `["red", "blue", "green"]` and I would expect it to be converted into a `enum Color { red, blue, green }`

Answer (score 5):

**[Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) «** *Enums allow us to define a set of named constants. Using enums can make it easier to document intent, or create a set of distinct cases. TypeScript provides both numeric and string-based enums.*

TypeScript <sup>[2.4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/27/announcing-typescript-2-4/)+</sup>  [**String enums**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/27/announcing-typescript-2-4/#string-enums) - Prior to TypeScript 2.4, TypeScript only supported number-based enums in that case just cast the string literal to `any` before assigning, Using 2.4+ then any would be no longer necessary

```
enum Colors {
    RED = <any>"R",
    GREEN = <any>"G",
    BLUE = <any>"B",
}
```

Java script <sup>[Standard Style](https://standardjs.com/)</sup>

```
var Colors;
(function (Colors) {
    Colors["RED"] = "r";
    Colors["GREEN"] = "g";
    Colors["BLUE"] = "b";
})(Colors || (Colors = {}));
```

Check in TypeScript Fiddle [fiddlesalad](http://fiddlesalad.com/typescript/), [typescriptlang](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

---

Below Utility function to create a [`K:V`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/literal-types.html) from a list of strings may help you.

```
function strEnum<T extends string>(o: Array<T>): {[K in T]: K} {
  return o.reduce((res, key) => {
    res[key] = key;
    return res;
  }, Object.create(null));
}
let dynamicArrayJSON = [ 'RED', 'BLUE', 'GREEN' ]
const Colors = strEnum( dynamicArrayJSON )
```

@see

- [How to create enum like type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40740721/5081877)
- [Create an enum with string values in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15490560/5081877)
- [When to use a semicolon in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089473/5081877)
- [Typescript `enum` from JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44906580/5081877)

Comment: I want to convert the above `object` type to an `enum` type.

Comment: static json object or dynamic json object you want to convert to enum

Comment: dynamic `JSON object`

Comment: see the utility function which may help you!

Comment: This is ace! I've been looking for a way to do this, thanks!