# typescript object type doesn't show error for omitting semi-colon

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found a strange thing with object type declaration. I expect the p2 is the correct one, but it worked with a `,` or even I omit the semi-colon, it's still fine. Why is it so inconsistent?

```
let p: {
    x: number,
    y: string
} = {
    x: 1,
    y: "abc",
}


let p2: {
    x: number;
    y: string
} = {
    x: 1,
    y: "abc",
}


let p3: {
    x: number
    y: string
} = {
    x: 1,
 ...
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBADgXBDeAoCKIA84DsCuBbARiAE4A0yqAnnAM5hECWmA5ogL4QC8C5KGEAjGVQQqEAEQBDfAGMxZVokWhIUAExwkwvjgLEA3DxE06jFuy6bUfQYdGSZctosTLoAZg2HteQkVvGGZjZObi04G2E7KVl5RSA)

Answer (score 2):

Semicolons in JavaScript are optional due to Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI). TypeScript follows ASI, too. ASI is not straightforward and there are a few situations where omitting a semicolon will lead to an unexpected runtime error. But the few corner cases in JavaScript are further eliminated by TypeScript’s type system.

```
// valid
class Employee{
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

// also valid
class Employee{
  name: string
  age: number
}
```

Here is a link of a similar question that might help you--
[Are semicolons necessary in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004223/are-semicolons-necessary-in-typescript-2)

Comment: Please have a look at it-- [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas ]

Comment: the comma is between p variable, not trailing comma

Comment: I could not understand which comma are you talking about, all i can see in the ques is trailing commas..