# Cannot access array before initilaisation during swap

Tags: javascript

Ive come to something strange

Im trying to swap the array value 0 with the array value 1

Ive found a previous post stating that this is possible

```
[arr[0], arr[1]] = [arr[1], arr[0]];
```

So I wanted to replicate that

```
let array_names = ["Dave", "johson", "Lime", "Key", "Freeman", "Chell", "Shepart", "Furious"]
[array_names[0], array_names[1]] = [array_names[1], array_names[0]]
```

However something strange happens

I get an error message stating that

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'array_names' before initialization
```

I have checked and there isnt a typo anywhere

Also yes I did initialize the array before doing any modificiation

Comment: This is probably due to the lack of `;` to terminate a statement. The second line is combined with the statement of the first line. So `let names = ["a", "b", "c"][names[0], names[1]] ...`, which probably results in the error. Try adding a semicolon `;` at the end of each statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it appropriate to use a semicolon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823062/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-a-semicolon)

Comment: also [Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is totally correct, but due to a missing semicolon, the interpreter parsed your code differently..

```
let array_names = ["Dave", "johson", "Lime", "Key", "Freeman", "Chell", "Shepart", "Furious"]
[array_names[0], array_names[1]] = [array_names[1], array_names[0]]
```

The expression was evaluated as

```
["Dave", "johson", ...][array_names[0], array_names[1]]
```

The code is parsed as one line statement.

The right answer as stated by Shubhada is

```
let array_names = ["Dave", "johson", "Lime", "Key", "Freeman", "Chell", "Shepart", "Furious"]; //Terminate statement
[array_names[0], array_names[1]] = [array_names[1], array_names[0]];
```

Answer (score 2):

JS is actually trying to interpret your code as :

```
// reduced for brevity
let array_names = ["Dave", "johson"][array_names[0], array_names[1]] = [array_names[1], array_names[0]]
```

It's trying to access the index `[array_names[0], array_names[1]]` of the array `["Dave", "johson"]` and at that time, `array_names` not yet defined.

You can (should) use semicolon to fix that :

```js
let array_names = ["Dave", "johson", "Lime", "Key", "Freeman", "Chell", "Shepart", "Furious"];
[array_names[0], array_names[1]] = [array_names[1], array_names[0]];
console.log(array_names);
```

Answer (score 1):

I try following

```js
let array_names = [
  "Dave", "johson",
  "Lime", "Key",
  "Freeman", "Chell", 
  "Shepart", "Furious"
]

console.log(array_names)

array_names[0], array_names[1] = array_names[1], array_names[0]

console.log(array_names)

temp = array_names[0]
array_names[0] = array_names[1]
array_names[1] = temp

console.log(array_names)
```

and get the result

```
[
  'Dave',    'johson',
  'Lime',    'Key',
  'Freeman', 'Chell',
  'Shepart', 'Furious'
]
[
  'Dave',    'johson',
  'Lime',    'Key',
  'Freeman', 'Chell',
  'Shepart', 'Furious'
]
[
  'johson',  'Dave',
  'Lime',    'Key',
  'Freeman', 'Chell',
  'Shepart', 'Furious'
]
```

as in [here](https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3yyb8ac4u). But with your code I obtain

```
[
  'Dave',    'johson',
  'Lime',    'Key',
  'Freeman', 'Chell',
  'Shepart', 'Furious'
]
[
  'Dave',    'johson',
  'Lime',    'Key',
  'Freeman', 'Chell',
  'Shepart', 'Furious'
]
```

where the elements are not swapped. I do not understand either.

Comment: This answer is missing the `[` and `]` around the two sides of the `=`. `array_names[0], array_names[1] = array_names[1], array_names[0]` is executed as `array_names[0]` followed by `array_names[1] = array_names[1]` followed by `array_names[0]`. Which is not the same as `[array[0], array[1]] = [array[1], array[0]]` which uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to swap the elements.